# EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink -> Router)

Tags: angular

I am trying to make the route working but getting following error. My goal is to load default component on page load and then when user clicks from navigation can load more routes.

First I am trying to load the default router but getting this following errors. Right now I kept the router link and RouterOutlet both in app.component.ts.

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink -> Router).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component for route "/home" is not defined, or is not a class.
```

my app component is like is here

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import {ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES, DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES, Collapse} from "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap";
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/common";
import {MyAppComponent} from "./components/myapp.component";
import {RouterLink} from "angular2/router";
import {RouterOutlet} from "angular2/router";


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:`<a [routerLink]="['Home']">Heroes</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet><myapp></myapp>`,
    directives:[ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES, DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES,
        RouterLink,Collapse, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, MyAppComponent, RouterOutlet],
    providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

//Router configuration
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Home',
        component:'HomeComponent',
        useAsDefault: true
    }
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

My main.ts looks like this

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";

bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

If anyone know whats wrong in my code then please let me know...

Comment: Remove ROUTE_PROVIDERS from the component.

Comment: Do I need to remove from the app.component ?

Comment: Yes, you should have it only in your bootstrap.

Comment: No doesn't work. its showing the same error.

Comment: Change all your imports to use single quotes, mixing single quotes with double quotes causes issues. Also remove `RouterLink` and `RouterOutlet` from your directives, you're already including them with `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`. Keep `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` out of your component providers.

Comment: Not lucky with that too... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` from all components. Add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` only to

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS])
```

Answer (score 0):

First do as Eric stated,

Then, I think the problem is with `HomeComponent`. Once you define any route in `RouteConfig`, **you have to import all defined routes components**.

So I think this should fix your problem,

```
import {HomeComponent} from 'HomeComponent path';
```